# how to get the index value after the img is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

It might be easier to explain my question with the actual code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var username_array = [];
    var text_array = [];
    var virtual_name;

    $(document).ready(function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor= "rgb(0, 188, 237)";
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    if(name!=null){
    x = "Hello " + name + "!";
    a = document.createElement("p");
    a.innerHTML=x;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    b = document.createElement("p");
    b.addEventListener('click',question,false);
    b.style.cursor='pointer';
    b.style.textDecoration="underline";
    b.innerHTML="Check out what you look like on Twitter."
    document.body.appendChild(b);
    }


    function question () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+name+'&callback=?&rpp=5',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                    for(i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
                        pic = data.results[i].profile_image_url;
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute("id", "profile"+i);
                        img.src=pic;
                        img.width=50;
                        img.height=50;
                        img.addEventListener('click', realname, false);
                        img.style.cursor='pointer';
                        document.body.appendChild(img);
                        username = data.results[i].from_user_name;
                        username_array.push(username);
                        text = data.results[i].text;
                        text_array.push(text);
                        sequence = i;
                    }
                check_array();
            }
        })
        c = document.createElement("p");
        c.innerHTML="Which one is you?"
        document.body.appendChild(c);
    }
    });

    function check_array() {
    }

    var sequence;

    function realname() {
        i=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
        d = document.createElement("p");
        d.innerHTML="Here is your virtual name: " + username_array[i];
        document.body.appendChild(d);

        e = document.createElement("p");
        e.innerHTML= username_array[i] +" actually has something to say to you:";
        e.style.textDecoration="underline";
        e.addEventListener('click',say,false);
        e.style.cursor="pointer";
        document.body.appendChild(e);

        sequence = i;
    }
</script>
```

the problem i have is this line:

```
function realname() {
        i=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
 ...}
```

and

```
img.addEventListener('click', realname, false);
```

Ideally, I want the user to click the img and I can get the index value of it and pass it to the realname function, so I can get the correct username which matches the profile image from the data.result. Right now the random "i" I generate inside function realname is just fake in order to get something appears.

I am not sure if I explain it clear enough. 
Thank you for anyone can help.

Comment: what do you mean by index value

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry about my unclear explanation. By index value, I mean the right image that the user has clicked. Say if the image is the first one of the array, than in the function "realname", I can know it is the first image that has been clicked, which should be Array[0] and get the first user_name from the array. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you intended to do: http://jsfiddle.net/whizkid747/f77Ym/

I changed the way you attach click event to image dynamically generated:

```
$("img").click(function(event){
    //alert(event.target.id);
    realname(event.target.id.replace("profile",""));

    });
```

This code will attach click event on all the images in your DOM. you may need to change it so that click is attached only to images in a particular div. Now from the id of the image, we are removing the string profile so that you get the index number.

Even though this example works, you are trying to do this in a very complicated way, if you think jQuery way, this functionality can be written with less complexity and code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've make some changes to the dom manipulation to convert them to use jQuery

```
var username_array = [];
var text_array = [];
var virtual_name;

$(function() {
            $('body').css('background-color', rgb(0, 188, 237));

            var name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
            if (name != null) {
                x = "Hello " + name + "!";

                $('<div>' + x + '</div>').appendTo('body');

                $('<p>' + "Check out what you look like on Twitter." + '</p>')
                        .appendTo('body').css({
                                    cursor : 'pointer',
                                    textDecoration : "underline"
                                }).click(question);
            }

            function question() {
                $.ajax({
                            url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='
                                    + name + '&callback=?&rpp=5',
                            type : 'GET',
                            dataType : 'json',
                            success : function(data) {
                                for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                                    pic = data.results[i].profile_image_url;

                                    $('<img class="proile-pic" id="' + "profile" + i + '"></img>')
                                            .appendTo('body').attr('src', pic)
                                            .attr('width', 50).height('width',
                                                    50)
                                            .css('cursor', 'pointer').click(
                                                    function() {
                                                        var index = $('.proile-pic').index(this);
                                                        realname(index);
                                                    });

                                    username = data.results[i].from_user_name;
                                    username_array.push(username);
                                    text = data.results[i].text;
                                    text_array.push(text);
                                    sequence = i;
                                }
                                check_array();
                            }
                        })
                c = document.createElement("p");
                c.innerHTML = "Which one is you?"
                document.body.appendChild(c);
            }
        });

function check_array() {
}

var sequence;

function realname(i) {
    d = document.createElement("p");
    d.innerHTML = "Here is your virtual name: " + username_array[i];
    document.body.appendChild(d);

    e = document.createElement("p");
    e.innerHTML = username_array[i] + " actually has something to say to you:";
    e.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    e.addEventListener('click', say, false);
    e.style.cursor = "pointer";
    document.body.appendChild(e);

    sequence = i;
}
```